How do you get a document ID from a published Google Doc?
I have been trying to use the Google Docs API to retrieve the contents of a published document, however I realised that the ID in the URL is not a document ID. So does anyone have a clue as to how I can retrieve the document ID?
If there isn't a way to for me to get the document ID, is there another way to access the document through the docs API?

I do think that this question was coming from a staging ground, and it is now has less information which URL you are trying to pull the Document ID from, for the sake of the future reader's information. As what Tanaike's comment. As of the moment and based on your case and which Document ID was actually being tried to be pulled it is not supported and not available.
